# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, routes, ruby-on-rails-5.2

While testing my controller action I am getting this routing error. I am not able to figure it out where I am doing it wrong

**route**

```
 get ':user_type', to: 'user_posts#index', param: :user_type, constraints: lambda { |req| ['abc', 'def'].include?(req.params["user_type"]) }, as: :custom_posts
```

**Spec:**

```
  describe "GET #index: enabled" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :index, params: {user_type: 'abc'}
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
```

Error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"user_posts"}
```

Also, I tried one solution on [github](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1699) by changing my route but it didn't work for me

```
get ':user_type', to: 'user_posts#index', param: :user_type, constraints: {user_type: lambda { |req| ['abc', 'def'].include?(req.params["user_type"]) } }, as: :custom_posts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got an answer. Here is the detail [discussion](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/2214)

```
describe "GET #index: enabled" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :index, params: { user_type: 'abc', param: :user_type }     
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
```